# R subsetting list "incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: r, list, subset

I am working with some text in a list. The text is separated by CR/LF, so I split the string on that. Then I have to clean up the list to make it usable.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_list <-("abc\r\ndef\r\nghi\r\njkl\r\n")
```

```
# The str_split gives me a list that has an empty element at the end. Why?
split_list <- str_split(my_list, "\r\n")
[[1]]
[1] "abc" "def" "ghi" "jkl" ""
```

I need to remove the first two elements and then sort in reverse order:

```
split_list %>%
  split_list[[1]][-1:-2] %>%
  sort(split_list, decreasing = TRUE)
```

But it fails with `Error in.[split_list[[1]], -1:-2] : incorrect number of dimensions`

I've read so many discussions of subsetting but they all seem *more* complicated than my example. I clearly don't understand this yet. Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error that you have mentioned. I get the expected output although I don't think that is the right way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, @RonakShah. I edited my example slightly. It should fail now. This is my first post ever, so I'm still learning.

Comment: Yes, it does fail now. You can have a look at my answer which should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way of using "[[" and "[" inside the tidyverse framework. They are both functions so you need to `backtick` them when they are used in this manner. (Your error arises from referring to the data-object twice. You should not need to refer to `split_list` twice.) The `tidyverse` creates an implicit pass-through of the leading data-object as it gets progressively modified by the sequence of functions. Functions become somewhat like 'infix'-functions in base R:

```
split_list %>%
     `[[`(1) %>%   # pulls first column from split_list
     `[`(-1:-2) %>%  # both extraction functions used by back-ticked names
     sort( decreasing = TRUE)
[1] "jkl" "ghi" ""
```

It's actually quite similar to the arrangement you could use in the base R use of these functions which are also infix:

```
sort( split_list
            [[ 1]]
            [ (-1:-2)], 
                decreasing = TRUE)

[1] "jkl" "ghi" ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
library(magrittr)
split_list %>% .[[1]] %>% tail(-2) %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE)
#[1] "jkl" "ghi" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only working on one vector such that `str_split` only ever returns a list with one element containing the split vector, you could wrap your `str_split()` inside the `unlist()` function to obtain the vector of split elements directly. It could look something like this:

```
sort(unlist(str_split(my_list, "\r\n"))[-c(1:2)], decreasing = TRUE)
```

Above I also subset the unlisted vector to remove the first two elements and then wrap the entire expression inside the `sort()` function with `decreasing = TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you, @edsandorf. I prefer the pipe method for readability, but I appreciate your input.